# Let $f : M \to M $ - bijection of a finite set. Then $f^n = Id_M$ for some $n \in N$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f : M \to M $ - bijection of a finite set. Then $f^n = Id_M$ for some $n \in N$.Give an example of a bijection of an infinite set, for which this statement is false.

Could you please provide any hints or give clarification ? I do not understand this problem.

I will try to construct my own proof

> Let $f : Z \to Z$ such that $f(x) = 2*x$. Then with each $n$th iteration $f$, elemenets can be divided by $2^n$. Therefore, there will never be $n \in N$  such that $f^n = Id_M$, since elements such as 1, 3, 5 cannot be divided by $2^n$ for any $n \in N$.

Comment: non-infinite = finite?

Comment: @azifmedrano Sorry))) I forgot the word 'finite' )

Comment: Your counter example looks fine (although the argument can be made a bit simpler), but it still doesn't give a proof of the claim for finite sets - only shows that it's not true in the infinite case.

Comment: If the set $Z$ in your attempt is the set of integers, then $f(x)=2x$ is not a bijection $Z\to Z$ since it isn't surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set $S_M:=\{f:M\to M|\text{ } f\text{ is a bijection }\}$ and endow it with the operation of composition. This is a finite group, namely the symmetry group on $M$, so all of its elements have finite order.

For the infinite case, take for example $M=\mathbb{Z}$ and consider the bijection $f(n)=n+1$. Obviously as many times we compose $f$ with itself we will never reach the identity.

Answer (score 0):

Hint - choose some $a\in M$ and look at the sequence $a_n=(f^n(a))_{n=0}^{\infty}$. Can this sequence be non-recurring? If not, what can you conclude?

Repeat this for all $a\in M$ and try to think what you can say about $f$ after enough iterations.

Comment: I can't make an example where this sequence is non-reccuring. Does it mean that there is no such infinite set for which this statement is false ?

Comment: If you think about it (this is the challenging part of the proof), you'll see that the sequence has to be recurring - there cannot be any counter example (at least in the finite case). Then, since the sequence must be recurrent, then there is some index $n$ such that $f^n(a)=a$, as you wished to prove.

Comment: To make things simpler, you can even show that there are two distinct $m,n$ such that $a_n=a_m$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do I understand this question right ? Suppose $f:Z \to Z$. and $f(x) = -1 * x$. Then f is such a bijection that is defined in hypothesis, right ?

Comment: @RustemSadykov I think what they wanted is a counter example through an infinite set, this is not a counter example

Comment: Please have a look at the proof I have written